# Error: (Hidden field word) Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.(Django)

Tags: django, widget

I'm receiving this error after making a selection and hitting submit. I'm not sure how it fix it.I'm trying to hide using HiddenInput in the forms on the page. Is there another way to do it other than on the forms.py

Models.py

```
from django.db import models from django.utils import timezone
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from random import randrange

class Type(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def _unicode__(self):
        return self.type

class WordManager(models.Manager):

    def random(self, type):
       words = Word.objects.filter(type__type=type)

       return words[randrange(len(words))]


class Word(models.Model):
    dict = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    type = models.ForeignKey(Type)

    objects = WordManager()

    def __unicode__(self):
       return u'%s %s' % (self.dict, self.type)

class Question(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.question


class Meta(models.Model):
    user = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    time = models.DateTimeField('date published')

class Result(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    word = models.ManyToManyField(Word)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    score = models.IntegerField()
```

Forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.forms import ModelForm

from quest.models import Result, Question, Word

class ResultForm(ModelForm):
    CHOICES = (
('1', '1'), ('2','2'), ('3','3'), ('4', '4'), ('5', '5')
)
question = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Question.objects.all(), widget=forms.HiddenInput())
word = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Word.objects.all(), widget=forms.HiddenInput())
user = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.all(), widget=forms.HiddenInput())
score = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES, widget=forms.RadioSelect())

class Meta:
    model = Result


class UserForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
       model = User
       fields = ('username',)
```

Views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.utils import timezone

from random import randrange
import re

from quest.models import Word, Type, Question, Meta
from quest.forms import ResultForm, UserForm

def index(request):
    state = "Enter ID and password below"
    username = password = ''
    if request.POST:
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                state = "You're successfully logged in!"
            else:
                state = "Your account is disabled."
        else:
            state = "Your username and password were incorrect."

     return render_to_response('index.html',{'state':state, 'username': username}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))


def question(request):
    # Find all words to be replaced from the question marked by '$'
    question = Question.objects.get(id=1)

    word_types = re.findall(r"\w+[$]", question.question)
    word_types = [find_w.rstrip("$") for find_w in word_types]
    words = [Word.objects.random(type) for type in word_types]

    question_text = question.question.replace("$", "")
    for word in words:
        question_text = question_text.replace(word.type.type, word.dict)
for word in words:
    question_text = question_text.replace(word.type.type, word.dict)

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = ResultForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('question'))
    else:
        for error in form.errors:
            print error
else:
    form = ResultForm(initial={'question': question.id, 'word': [word.id for word in words], 'user': request.user.id})

return render_to_response('quest/question.html', {'final': question_text, 'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
word = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Word.objects.all(), widget=forms.HiddenInput())
```

<strike>What's the point of being a choice field, if no one can choose it?</strike>
Ok, now I got what you're trying to do. But the below still applies.

Also this:

```
'word': [word.id for word in words]
```

in your `initial` form data is wrong. ModelChoiceField `presents` a lot of choices 
but only **one** can be selected. So `'word': someword.id` would be correct.

As a side note, maybe [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#order-by) would be useful on how to select random data from
a model.

Comment: Instead of word = form.ModelChoiceField(...), the problem was solved by adding word = form.ModelMultipleChoiceField(...). I originally thought the widget was providing the issue.

Comment: @ono3 If you actually want multiple values stored on the field then yes, ModelMultipleChoiceField is the correct field. I wasn't aware that that was your intention.